# Implementing PHP into website. How to call jquery function for each id from the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the test page:
http://grozav.com/test.php

I'm trying to add a jquery function to each image from the mysql database table.
Here is the generated code:

```
<div class="thumb" id="grozav-thumb">
<a class="ajax" href="gallery/grozav.html">
<p class="work-type">MOTION GRAPHICS</p>
<img src="http://grozav.com/images/thumbs/grozav-bwthumb.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="http://grozav.com/images/thumbs/grozav-thumb.jpg" alt="" class="color"/>
</a></div>
```

I need a function which creates a code for each div with the class thumbnail. The outcome should be like this:

*thumbnail() is a function

```
thumbnail('divid');
```

which is something like

```
thumbnail('grozav')
```

Thanks a lot!

---

After reading the advices here, I've changed the code into:

```
function thumbnail(param1){
$(param1).hover(
    function() {
        $(param1+' .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
    },
    function() {
        $(param1+' .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
    }
) ;                 
};

for(var p in document.querySelectorAll('div.thumb'))
```

### thumbnail(p.id);

EDIT
Problem solved.
I used the following jQuery code to do it, which seems to work fine.

```
$("div.thumb").each(function (){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  
    thumbnail(id);});
```

Applies the function to each of the divs created through php. Thank you anyway guys!

Comment: You need to show us the generated HTML/JS, not the PHP source code.

Comment: Open the javascript console, and see if it shows any errors. In chrome, you can do this by clicking view -> developer -> JavaScript console. In FireFox, you can find this console in the extra's menu somewhere.

Comment: What that function is supposed to do?

Comment: hit CTRL + SHIFT + J in frefox to bring up the JS console.

Comment: @AlexG.: Have you solved your problem? Your website seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I used the following jQuery code to do it, which seems to work fine.

```
$("div.thumb").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');  
    thumbnail(id);
});
```

Applies the function to each of the divs created through php. Thank you anyway guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your `thumbnail` function is defined in `$(document).ready(function(){`. This means, that the browser won't know about `thumbnail()` until the site is loaded completly. So when your browser stumbles upon `<script>thumbnail('img0');</script>` in your div it has no idea what this `thumbnail` means.

You should place the call of thumbnail right after your definition of thumbnail. Something like

```
function thumbnail(param1){
$('#'+param1+'-thumb').hover(
    function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').hide().stop().fadeTo(500,'1');
    },
    function() {
        $('#'+param1+'-thumb .color').stop().fadeTo(500,'0');
    }
) ;                 
};

for(var p in document.querySelectorAll('div.thumb'))
    thumbnail(p.id);
```

Maybe there's a better solution than this in jQuery, but this should satisfy your needs.

*EDIT*: Use the error console of your browser (in this case `[xx:xx:xx.xxx] thumbnail is not defined @ http://grozav.com/test.php#portfolio:119`) - it will help you to find your errors faster.

Comment: It's also worth noting that simply calling `<script>thumbnail('x');</script>` won't work, as it'll execute before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop: That's the statement of my first paragraph - just didn't use the word "DOM" but `$(document).ready...` ;).

Comment: I'm supposed to receive an outcome like: 

thumbnail('lifelovelies');  which is thumbnail('idfromdatabase')

How can I do that with your function?

Comment: @AlexG.: Just use the code above and replace your current definition of `thumbnail` with this. Every `<div>` has an ID='idfromdatabase' and a `class='thumbnail'`. In the last two lines I iterate through all divs tagged as thumbnail and call `thumbnail(div.id)`. And strip all `<script>thumbnail(xxx)</script>` tags from your code, as they won't work. EDIT: You edited your question a little too much, my answer won't help you anymore. Hint: strip '-thumb' in thumbnail, then everything should work fine.